# pandas python: csv becomes a dataframe to.dict how to access columns and do something with it

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have used pandas and created a dataframe from a csv file and made two values into a dictionary using to.dict function.

I now want to access those values that i put in inside the dictionary, how exactly do you do it?

```
with open("tweet_raw.csv") as csvfile:
    colnames = ['created_at', 'id', 'idstr', 'text1']
    rdr = pd.read_csv(csvfile, header=None,
                      names=colnames,
                      usecols=["created_at", "id", "idstr", 'text1']).set_index('created_at')['text1'].to_dict()

    values = rdr.values()
    #dict(zip(list(rdr.created_at), list(rdr.text1)))
    #pprint(rdr)

def sentenceTokeniser():
    zen = values(list(values)['text1'])
    zen.words
```

I am getting all sorts of error from dict object not callable. What is the correct way of accessing it?

Thanks

Comment: do you need to convert the df to a dict? Using df.loc seems like adequate method to slicing and dicing your csv's columns and rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the columns, you can use loc to get a Series object to access the columns. The index will be the column in set_index

```
rdr = pd.read_csv(csvfile, header=None,
                  names=colnames,
                  usecols=["created_at", "id", "idstr", 'text1']).set_index('created_at')
values = rdr.loc[:, 'text1']
print type(values)
```